# IoC - Autowiring for objects that are created inside of components

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

What bothers me about IoC and autowiring is the usability of IoC for objects that are created.

Lets say I have the a static Utils class, that is used across the system. When I decided to use IoC and DI, I easily changed Utils to be non-static and have all my components receive its instance.

However, auto-wiring works well only for components that are created during bootstrap, for objects that are created during run-time or as response of user operations, and that use Utils, auto-wiring doesn't work. Instead, I have to manually pass instance of Utils to every instance of every object that is created during runtime.

The only way around it that I can see is using the anti-pattern of passing the IoC container around, which I certainly wouldn't want to do.

Is there another way? Or am I forced to pass Utils manually around to every instance and class?

**Note:** This isn't a question of design. Sure, I could minimize the usage of this metaphorical Utils in various ways, but in many situations it is unavoidable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The only way around it that I can see is using the anti-pattern of
>   passing the IoC container around, which I certainly wouldn't want to
>   do.

The answer is simply: use an abstract factory.

By defining the factory interface in the application and the factory implementation in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) (your bootstrapper code) you can prevent using the Service Locator anti-pattern. This factory implementation can hold a reference to the container and call it to request instances. Because that implementation is part of your bootstrapping logic, that implementation is a infrastructure component, and you are [not using it as a service locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/).

Example:

```
public interface IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
    IUnitOfWork CreateNew();
}
```

Implementation in composition root:

```
internal class SimpleInjectorUnitOfWorkFactory
    : IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
    private readonly SimpleInjector.Container container;

    public SimpleInjectorUnitOfWorkFactory(Container container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public IUnitOfWork CreateNew()
    {
        return this.container.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's some thought material. I guess [Automatic Factory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2010/04/28/unity-2-0-automatic-builders.aspx) is also an option then?

Comment: Of course, but since you didn't tag your answer, I gave a general answer. Btw, I'm a fan of keeping things simple and doin't use any DI framework specific stuff, unless it really makes things simpler (and less code isn't simpler per se).

Comment: Good point. I do use Unity so I marked the question as such. You don't use DI frameworks? Doing DI manually can be such a chore, though... When you have several components, each wanting different constructor parameters (and I didn't even mention lifetime support of DI frameworks)... But then again, I am only a newbie with DI, so my opinion might yet change. Thanks!

Comment: @VitalyB: I looked at your profile as well :-). It reminded me that BugAid was a very cool VS plugin. I just applied for an Open Source license. Cheers!

Comment: Glad you like it, your license is on its way :) Will definitely take a look on Simple Injector as well.

Comment: If you want to know why you should pick Simple Injector over Unity, take a look at [this](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) article. It shows a design that is really hard to register using Unity.